# Grammar in tenses

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I'm writing something and I came across a dilemma, my friend told me the way I wrote it was wrong but I am certain I'm correct but I don't want to leave something that could be a mistake.. can someone tell me which of these two are correct and why? Or are they both correct(which is what I think)?

"I used to be so ugly"
"No, you didn't"

“I used to be so ugly”
“No, you weren’t”

Comment: Be it "didn't" or "weren't", or even "usen't", but without a comma after "no" it's all wrong anyway.

Comment: @YellowSky Yeah sorry,  its half four in the morning, I'm a little tired! Fixed it there

Comment: You can say "You didn't used to be so ugly" or "You weren't so ugly", so I think both verbs work.

Comment: @Yellow Sky I'd not mark "No you weren't!" wrong. The written form is an attempt to codify speech in the first instance (and certainly so in this example). If the speaker left no pause, the comma-less form is more accurate. There's no scope for misinterpretation here. People become enslaved to rules, insisting they be used even in cases where they would be better bypassed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Since the OP wrote, "I don't want to leave something that could be a mistake," I tried to attract some attention to the punctuation which was obviously ignored in the question, but, sadly, to no avail, there are still no sentence-terminal punctuation marks in the four example sentences. Or do you mean sentence-terminal punctuation should be better bypassed, too? Perhaps no, since you do use it, you even added an exclamation point. I'd better put an ellipsis instead, that would make it more dramatic.

Comment: @Yellow Sky '... without a comma after "no" it's all wrong anyway' is the statement you made. _I won't be returning to this thread._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The *correct* form is 'No, you *didn't*.'**

[The grammar section](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/used-to) of the Cambridge Dictionary confirms that:

> The most common form of question is auxiliary ***did*** + *use(d)* to. Many people consider the form with a final *-d* to be incorrect, and you should not use it in exams:
>
> *I think we met once, a couple of years ago. **Did** you **use to** work with Kevin Harris?*

Tag questions also have **did**/**didn't**:

> We normally make tags after *used to* with auxiliary **did**:
>
> *He used to be your boss, **did** he*?
>
> *We used to love going to the museum, **didn’t** we?*

Also, in the negative form, *used to* becomes ***didn’t** use(d) to*:

> The negative of *used to* is most commonly ***didn’t** use(d) to*. Sometimes we write it with a final *-d*, sometimes not. Both forms are common, but many people consider the form with the final *-d* to be incorrect, and you should not use it in exams:
>
> *It **didn’t use to** be so crowded in the shops as it is nowadays.*

Now, the sentence *I used to be so ugly.* All the syntactic transformation of this sentence involve **did**/**didn't**:

> Affirmative: *I **used to** be so ugly.*
> Negative: *I **didn't use to** be so ugly.*
> General question: ***Did** I **use to** be so ugly?*
> Tag question: *I **used to** be so ugly, **didn't I**?*

Naturally, any answer to the question ***Did** I **use to** be so ugly?* or *I **used to** be so ugly, **didn't I**?* will also contain **did**/**didn't**:

> Affirmative: Yes, you **did**.
> Negative: No, you **didn't**.